# Best practice for parsing Request arguments Python (Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, http, flask

I have the next function in my controller.py:

```
@app.route('/api/model/train', methods=['POST'])
def create_train_model():
    """
    Create and train new model.

    """
    args = request.json

    train_booster(arg1 = 100, arg2 = True, arg3 = 'sgd')

    return jsonify(success=True)
```

And, as you can see, some function into it (from service.py) with 3 arguments and default parameters.

How I can take from request body parameters and pass them to function?
I found this solution:

```
class ModelArguments:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.arg1 = 100
        self.arg2 = True
        self.arg3 = 'sgd'

        self.__dict__.update(args)

@app.route('/api/model/train', methods=['POST'])
def create_train_model():
    """
    Create and train new model.

    """
    model_arguments = ModelArguments(request.json)

    train_booster(arg1 = model_arguments.arg1,
                  arg2 = model_arguments.arg2,
                  arg3 = model_arguments.arg3,)

    return jsonify(success=True)
```

**Are there any better (or PythonWay or more safe/useful) realizations?**
For example, if I will change function `train_booster` and now it will take one more argument I need to rewrite every layer of my project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a idea, as follows.
service.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask("aaa")


def func1(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3


def func2(arg4=1, arg5=2):
    print arg4, arg5


def func3(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4=1, arg5=1):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5


@app.route('/api/model/args_kwargs', methods=['POST'])
def create_train_model():
    """
    Create and train new model.

    """
    args, kwargs = request.json
    func3(*args, **kwargs)

    return jsonify(success=True)

@app.route('/api/model/args', methods=['POST'])
def create_train_2():
    """
    Create and train new model.

    """
    args = request.json
    func1(*args)

    return jsonify(success=True)

@app.route('/api/model/kwargs', methods=['POST'])
def create_train_3():
    """
    Create and train new model.

    """
    kwargs = request.json
    func2(**kwargs)

    return jsonify(success=True)

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9900)
```

client.py

```
import requests
import json

def test1():
    resp = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:9900/api/model/args", json=[12,3,4])
    return None

def test2():
    resp = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:9900/api/model/kwargs", json={"arg4":234, "arg5":678})
    return None

def test3():
    resp = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0:9900/api/model/args_kwargs", json=([12,3,4], {"arg4":234, "arg5":678}))
    return None


test1()
test2()
test3()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought about `**` operation. But my approach has one advantage: it will not fall if I add any new argument in body request (I mean if someone add excees unnecessary information) - this field will be ignored. When your approach (which is much shorter but) will fall.

Comment: or, maybe, you think my case (about additional info) is not correct? And more correct is to return error message if some arguments in POST request are wrong?

Comment: I update my answer,  just because i find my first answer is not clear and simple enough. I think you are right about the advantage of your approach.